# Copy the order of an array before sorting another array

Tags: javascript

How I can copy the order from another array before it was sorted? I have this:

```
function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return a-b;
}
arr2.sort(arr1 order) // here I need to sort the order
arr1.sort(sortNumber);
```

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: What do you mean, copy the order? Do you want to make a copy of the array?

Comment: With copy I mean this: arr1 has the values 25, 10, 5. I sort it like above with the function sortNumber. So the indexes of arr1 will be changed 0 will be 2, 1 will be 1 and 2 will be 0. Now I want sort arr2 so that it has the order of arr1 before it was sorted. Also the original order.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to sort an array, but also be able to 'unsort' / 'revert sort' that array or other arrays. e.g. given you sort the array `[1, 3, 2]`, you would then want to be able to unsort `['a', 'b', 'c']` to `['a', 'c', 'b']`.

This snippet could get you started, but note, it does't handle duplicates well (your description is ambiguous on what the desired behavior would be for duplicates).

```js
let sort = (arr, comparator) => {
  let orig = [...arr];
  arr.sort(comparator);
  let unsort = arr2 => {
    let sorted = [];
    arr2.forEach((v, i) => sorted [orig.indexOf(arr[i])] = v);
    return sorted;
  };
  return {sorted: arr, unsortFunction: unsort};
};

let array = [5, 2, 9, 6];
let array2 = ['two', 'five', 'six', 'nine'];
let comparator = (a, b) => a - b;

let {sorted, unsortFunction} = sort(array, comparator);
let unsorted2 = unsortFunction(array2);

console.log(sorted); // 2, 5, 6, 9
console.log(unsorted2); // 'five', 'two', 'nine', 'six'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get arr2 in the same permutation (starting from its sorted state) as arr1 (starting from its sorted state), you could replace:

```
arr2.sort(arr1 order)
```

with:

```
arr2.sort(sortNumber).splice(0, arr2.length, 
    ...arr1.map((x,i) => [x,i])
           .sort(([a],[b]) => a-b)
           .reduce((acc, [x,i], j) => (acc[i]=arr2[j], acc), [])
);
```

It is required that both arrays have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the indices and sort it by taking the values of the array.

```js
var array = [25, 10, 5],
    indices = [...array.keys()],
    sorted;

indices.sort((a, b) => array[a] - array[b]);
sorted = indices.map(i => array[i]);

console.log(indices);
console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```